# How to change the search URL like pretty URL in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I want change the search URL to pretty URL

**Search URL sample:**
http://example.com/office-search/?real_country=singapore&real_city=any

**Pretty URL like:**
http://example.com/office-search/singapore/any

I also wrote a rewrite rule, but it doesn't work me:

```
function search_url_rewrite_rule() {
    if (is_search() && !empty($_GET['real_country']) || !empty($_GET['real_city']) || !empty($_GET['real_district'])) {

        $c = $_GET['real_country'];
        $city =  $_GET['real_city'];
        $district =  $_GET['real_district'];

        wp_redirect( home_url("/office-search/?".$c."/".$city."/".$district) . urlencode( get_query_var('real_country') ) );
        exit();
    };
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'search_url_rewrite_rule');
```

Comment: Try this [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54832/wordpress-custom-search-url)  for custom URL rewrite

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I need to pass more then 2 parameters for search result.